# Lucene Boolean query not working in dot net

Tags: c#, lucene, search-engine, lucene.net

I am using Lucene dot net version 2.9 and constructed my query as following (GetQuery method). I could get the results from the same index using Luke tool with the same query. But not via dotnet API. Not sure is that a bug in Lucene.net? or a mistake on my part. Indexing is done with standard analyzer and analyzed all the fields that I am searching.

Note: It is working with Luke with the same index. I am using .net lucene 2.94 not Java Lucene libraries

The query that is working with Luke tool is this:

**+(content:polaris location:polaris) +ext:/pdf/xls/doc/docx**

Here is the c# code that is NOT working:

```
    private static BooleanQuery GetQuery(string term, string exts)
    {
        string[] fields = { MetaKeys.Content, MetaKeys.Location };
        MultiFieldQueryParser parser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(fields, new StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_29));

        Query multiFieldQuery = parser.Parse(term);
        TermQuery extQuery = new TermQuery(new Term(MetaKeys.Ext, exts));

        BooleanQuery combinedQuery = new BooleanQuery();
        combinedQuery.Add(multiFieldQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
        if (extQuery != null)
        {
            combinedQuery.Add(extQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
        }

        return combinedQuery;
    }
```

And it is used as following

```
        string exts = "/pdf/xls/doc/docx";
        BooleanQuery combinedQuery = GetQuery(term, exts);

        TopDocs docs = indexSearch.Search(combinedQuery, to);

        //resulting in 0 Hits
```

**Note to folks who closed my earlier question: give the original poster a chance (at least 24-hours) to correct it before you are going to close the question.**

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint at the return line and see what the query looks like at that point?

Comment: The query looks this: 
+(content:polaris location:polaris) +ext:/pdf/xls/doc/docx

It is working fine inside Luke

Comment: @Overture you create directly a TermQuery which doesn't make use of any analyzer. So your search string becomes `/pdf/xls/doc/docx`, but while using Luke you use an analyzer which possibly splits the string into parts `pdf`,`xls`.... Try with `KeywordAnalyzer` in Luke

Comment: I thought / as a term separator for Term as per an example I found in Lucene in Action book. I tried with space and comma as a term separator it didn't work either.

I probably need MultiTermQuery or something similar. Thanks for the clue.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you will find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15861904/net-lucene-why-wont-multifieldqueryparser-and-whitespaceanalyzer-query-in-boo) applicable: it works, and if you need any additional advice, you can ask me, I'm active on here! :)

Basically, it describes much the same thing as what you are doing, but it demonstrates some things that you are not doing right here; namely, using the constructed MultiFieldQueryParser object to parse input search terms and add them together using the BooleanQuery.